# ReactJS app not opening on Apache2 server

Tags: reactjs, npm, apache2

I've modified the package.json file with 'homepage' variable and run the 'npm run build' function, and moved the output files to the desired location.  However, the index.html page isn't being displayed - the icon appears, but the remaining links are missing, on deploying on apache2.

Comment: any errors you see in console \? maybe more info would help to help you :)

Comment: Yes, its unable to see the links in the file: 404 error, file not found!

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) index-B_HLYcso.css:1  
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) index-B_HLYcso.css:1 
        Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is the original index.html file:

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MS-0</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-DmLtFySu.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-B_HLYcso.css">
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

Comment: Also, this app was originally deployed in Vite:
# npm run build

> frontend@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v5.1.1 building for production...
✓ 236 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                     0.56 kB │ gzip:   0.36 kB
dist/assets/index-B_HLYcso.css    304.58 kB │ gzip:  44.37 kB
dist/assets/index-DmLtFySu.js   1,777.23 kB │ gzip: 414.15 kB

Comment: Seems that these lines are unable to find the files:
crossorigin src="/assets/index-DmLtFySu.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-B_HLYcso.css">